# Jquery - change href of link using the select tag which belongs to it

Tags: jquery, href, html-select

I have this code:

```html
<li class="list-group-item ui-sortable-handle">
      <a href="#" class="display">Contact</a>

      <select id="select" "="" name="pages">
        <option value="" selected="">Vyberte stránku</option>
        <option value="1">Admin-Stranka1</option>
        <option value="2">Admin-Stranka2</option>
        <option value="3">Admin-Stranka3</option>
        <option value="4">Admin-Stranka4</option>
      </select>
    </li>

    <li class="list-group-item ui-sortable-handle">
      <a href="#" class="display">Home</a>

      <select id="select" "="" name="pages">
        <option value="" selected="">Vyberte stránku</option>
        <option value="1">Admin-Stranka1</option>
        <option value="2">Admin-Stranka2</option>
        <option value="3">Admin-Stranka3</option>
        <option value="4">Admin-Stranka4</option>
      </select>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item ui-sortable-handle">
      <a href="#" class="display">About</a>

      <select id="select" "="" name="pages">
        <option value="" selected="">Vyberte stránku</option>
        <option value="1">Admin-Stranka1</option>
        <option value="2">Admin-Stranka2</option>
        <option value="3">Admin-Stranka3</option>
        <option value="4">Admin-Stranka4</option>
      </select>
    </li>
```

I would like to change the href of the link by setting the value of the select, which is next to the link

How can I do this? Thank you

Comment: Did you try something so far?

Comment: What problem are you having? `$(this).prev("a")` will get the link that's next to the select.

Comment: @Dekel I was looking for something like foreach. I am new at JQuery and I wasn't able to find a solution. I think I didn't know what should I look for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("select").each(function() { 
    $(this).change(function() {
        $(this).prev('a').attr('href',$(this).val());
    })
})
```

Comment: Still nothing. The href is not changing. The <select> tag is actually after the <a> tag